# Multiple references to a single table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two separate tables which refer to different country ID's and one country table. I'm having trouble reporting both of the country names. I know this is pretty basic but i'm pretty stuck so please help!

I have the following tables and columns:

```
Names
Reference_no    |Name   |Main_Country_ID
12345           |Name1  |1
12346           |Name2  |2
12347           |Name3  |1

Jobs
Reference_no    |Job      |Local_Country_ID
12345           |Job1     |3
12345           |Job2     |4
12346           |Job1     |1
12347           |Job1     |1

Country
Country_ID  |Country_Name
1           |UK
2           |US
3           |France
4           |Germany
```

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
Reference_no    |Name   |Main_Country_ID    |Country_Name   |Job        |Local_Country_ID   |Country_Name
12345           |Name1  |1                  |UK             |Job1       |3                  |France
12345           |Name1  |1                  |UK             |Job2       |4                  |Germany
12346           |Name2  |2                  |US             |Job1       |1                  |UK
12347           |Name3  |1                  |UK             |Job1       |1                  |UK
```

I have the following so far:

```
select n.reference_no,
       n.name,
       n.reference_no,
       c.country_name,
       j.job,
       j.local_country_id
       c2.country_name
from names n
join jobs j on n.reference_no=j.reference_no
join country c on n.main_country_id=c.country_id
join country c2 on j.local_country_id=c2.country_id
```

This SQL doesn't work as it doesn't like the 'c2' reference. Can anyone help me create this query?

Comment: So, what is the exact error??

Comment: I'm getting this odd feeling of two separate selects that are joined instead or even `union`'ed in.

Comment: The error i get is: ORA-00904: "COUNTRY"."ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 17 Column: 42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select n.reference_no,
       n.name,
       n.reference_no,
       c.country_name,
       j.job,
       j.local_country_id,
       c2.country_name
from names n
join jobs j on n.reference_no=j.reference_no
join country c on n.main_country_id=c.country_id
join country c2 on j.local_country_id=c2.country_id
```

Maybe you are missing the c2 in your join:

Comment: I don't think it likes me trying to join country twice.

Comment: I just adjusted as per your suggestion, I made a typo and forgot the C2 as you state but still getting an error: ORA-00904: "COUNTRY"."ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 16 Column: 74

Comment: Looks like I made an error in my code. Thanks for your help!